# How to solve Substrate `duplicate lang item in crate 'std' (which 'myexternalcrate' depends on): 'panic_impl' conflict with sr-io

Tags: substrate

I'm using an extern crate in my Substrate 1.0 runtime module (based on `node-template`) which gives a compile error of

```sh
duplicate lang item in crate 'std' (which 'myexternalcrate' depends on): 'panic_impl'.

= note: first defined in crate `sr_io` (which `node_template_runtime` depends on).
```

If I understand the message correctly then I think this might be a common problem if developers want to include external crates that rely on `std` features which already implemented in `sr-io`, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

I have seen this issue [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/2971), which appears to have been fixed in `sr-io` but that does not appear to be the cause here.

Is their another approach to resolve this?

**EDIT**: Adding in changes to `Cargo.toml`
We are attempting to pull in crate called nacl

```sh
[dependencies]
nacl = {version = "0.3.0", default-features = false}
```

Added in `lib.rs`

```rust
extern crate nacl;
```

in the runtime module

```rust
use nacl::public_box::*;
```

Comment: The issue is most certainly something related to `std`. See [this](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-module-template/blob/master/HOWTO.md#forgetting-cfg_attr-for-no_std) and [this](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-module-template/blob/master/HOWTO.md#adding-new-dependencies)

Comment: In general, can you share the changes you made in the `cargo.toml` file when importing the external crate?

Comment: Added more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crate you are trying to use (`rust-nacl`) does not support `no_std`, and thus cannot be used within the Substrate runtime environment.

The options are:

- Find another crate which does support `no_std` and has similar functionality: https://crates.io/keywords/no_std
- Update/Write a crate to support `no_std` (which may not be that bad depending on the crate).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Shawn Tabrizi's answer above...
To use another crate that supports no_std:

```
imported_crate = { git = "...", default-features = false, branch = "..." }
```

OR to write a crate to support no_std :

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

more about no_std: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-to-resolve-duplicate-lang-item-error

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error may occur when `node_template_runtime` is compiled with `std` in a no_std environment. So, in your above example, you should check if std is enabled for `node_template_runtime` and not enable it.